# Laravel 5.7 Шаблон письма подтверждения email

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

Вопрос по внешнему виду письма, которое приходит пользователю для верификации email в Laravel 5.7

Я понял, что могу перегрузить метод `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` в `User.php` и поменять тем самым текст внутри письма.

Но как можно изменить сам шаблон?